# How to use Multiple 'where' query on firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
   const q = query(
      jobsRef,
      where("jobtype", "==", jobCriteria.jobtype),
      where("title", "==", jobCriteria.title),
      where("location", "==", jobCriteria.location),
      where("experience", "==", jobCriteria.experience),
      orderBy("postedOn", "desc")
    );
```

in this code i'm trying to use multiple firebase `where` query it's not filtering the job Custom data but while i'm using single where so it's filtering the seprrate at one time like this

```
   const q = query(
      jobsRef,
      where("jobtype", "==", jobCriteria.jobtype),
      orderBy("postedOn", "desc")
    );
```

now the code is working fine while using single where !

please give me the solution how can i use multiple `where`query on Firebase !

Comment: Please edit the question to show any error message you're getting after executing the query.  Also, we can't see the values of the variables or the data you're working with, so we can't tell what these queries are supposed to do in practice.  If the queries are returning unexpected results, your question should explain that in more detail using specific data.

Comment: Most likely you're missing a necessary (composite) index. This problem comes up here multiple times a week, so I recommend searching for https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D+multiple+conditions and https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing